# SQL (MySQL) Query To Extract Aggregates Over Multiple Timeframes

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have the following table, my_table:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
+ key_code + cost_value + cost_date  +
+----------+------------+------------+
+   AAAA   +       1.01 + 2015-01-05 +
+   AAAA   +       4.04 + 2015-01-10 +
+   AAAA   +       3.03 + 2015-01-15 +
+   AAAA   +       2.02 + 2015-01-20 +
+   BBBB   +       5.05 + 2015-01-05 +
+   BBBB   +       8.08 + 2015-01-10 +
+   BBBB   +       7.07 + 2015-01-15 +
+   BBBB   +       6.06 + 2015-01-20 +
+----------+------------+------------+
```

I can extract the minimum and maximum cost_values for each key_code with the following query:

```
SELECT key_code, MIN(cost_value) AS cost_min, MAX(cost_value) AS cost_max 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY key_code 
ORDER BY key_code;

+----------+----------+----------+
+ key_code + cost_min + cost_max +
+----------+----------+----------+
+   AAAA   +     1.01 +     4.04 +
+   BBBB   +     5.05 +     8.08 +
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I can limit the min/max to cost_values from the last 7 days (assume Today = 2015-01-21) with the following query:

```
SELECT key_code, MIN(cost_value) AS cost_min_07, MAX(cost_value) AS cost_max_07 
FROM my_table 
WHERE cost_date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY key_code 
ORDER BY key_code;

+----------+-------------+-------------+
+ key_code + cost_min_07 + cost_max_07 +
+----------+-------------+-------------+
+   AAAA   +        2.02 +        3.03 +
+   BBBB   +        6.06 +        7.07 +
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

But what if I want to extract min/max for the previous 7, 14 and 21 days simultaneously? How can I (most efficiently) generate the following result? I guess I'm asking how to apply a different WHERE to each MIN() and MAX() pair?

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
+ key_code + cost_min_07 + cost_max_07 + cost_min_14 + cost_max_14 + cost_min_21 + cost_max_21 +
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
+   AAAA   +        2.02 +        3.03 +        2.02 +        4.04 +        1.01 +        4.04 +
+   BBBB   +        6.06 +        7.07 +        6.06 +        8.08 +        5.05 +        8.08 +
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I would look into table aliases, but I have never tried doing different groups within one sql statement. Maybe make some views for the different date ranges and then combine them.

Comment: You may prefer to have the results in rows rather than columns, for scalability, and then handle the formatting in your presentation layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT key_code,
       MIN(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL  7 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_min_07,           
       MAX(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL  7 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_max_07, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_min_14,           
       MAX(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_max_14, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_min_21,           
       MAX(CASE WHEN cost_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY THEN cost_value END) AS cost_max_21 
FROM my_table 
WHERE cost_date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY) 
GROUP BY key_code 
ORDER BY key_code;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon - works perfectly and seems 'elegant' code. I'd never seen the CASE construct before - sometimes it just helps to know what to look for!

Answer (score 1):

You can group result by key_code and period. To get proper period, we shift dates in the basis `7`, assuming that `CURRENT_DATE()` is end of period. Try query bellow. `d_min` - period start, `d_max` - period end, `d_diff` - differance in periods between current date and period date.

```
set @base=7;
set @v=TO_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE());
set @diff=@base-@v%@base-1;
set @vb=FLOOR((@v+@diff)/@base);

SELECT
    FROM_DAYS(t.vb*@base-@diff) AS d_min,
    FROM_DAYS((t.vb+1)*@base-@diff-1) AS d_max,
    FLOOR(@vb-t.vb) AS d_diff,
    t.key_code,
    t.cost_min,
    t.cost_max
FROM (
SELECT
    key_code,
    MIN(cost_value) AS cost_min,
    MAX(cost_value) AS cost_max,
    FLOOR((TO_DAYS(cost_date)+@diff)/@base) as vb
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    key_code, vb
ORDER BY
    vb DESC, key_code
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks, Max. I didn't try your code, as Gordon's reply seemed more 'elegant', so I can't vouch for the performance trade-offs between his and your solutions. Perhaps you could comment?